# TypeScript Module not found with the right import path

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I am using Vue cil to construct a project, and I am using TypeScript in it as well. I just encountered a problem after compile:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './userAPI' in 'A:\学科文件\front end\movie_booking_system\src\components\Service'

ERROR in ./src/components/Service/Service.ts 4:16-36
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './userAPI' in 'A:\学科文件\front end\movie_booking_system\src\components\Service'
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??clonedRuleSet-40.use[0]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!./src/views/User/RegistrationPage.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js 2:0-58 57:6-31
 @ ./src/views/User/RegistrationPage.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js 1:0-214 1:0-214 1:215-418 1:215-418
 @ ./src/views/User/RegistrationPage.vue 2:0-67 3:0-62 3:0-62 8:49-55
 @ ./src/router.js 3:0-61 16:13-29
 @ ./src/main.js 6:0-30 7:19-25
```

My folder sturcture is as follow:

```
|--src
|    |--...
|    |--components
|            |--...
|            |--Service
|                  |--Service.ts
|                  |--userAPI.ts
|                  |--DataModel.ts
|                  |--Request.ts
|--tsconfig.json
|--babel.config.ts
|--vue.config.tsjs
|--jsconfig.json
|--package.json
|--package-lock.json
```

And my userAPI.ts:

```
import {request} from "./Request";
import {UserData} from "./DataModel";


export class UserAPI{
    constructor() {

    }

    registerUser(user:UserData)
    {
        return request('register',user).then(response=>{
            console.log("注册成功：",response);
        }).catch(error=>{
            console.error("注册失败！",error);
        });
    }

    userLogin(user:UserData){

    }
}

// export const User=new UserAPI();
```

And my Service.ts:

```
import { UserAPI } from "./userAPI";

export class Service{
    user:UserAPI;
    constructor() {
        this.user=new UserAPI();
    }
}

// export const service=new Service();
```

Additionally, my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

I am trying to figure out why the seemingly right import path didn't work?
How can I solve this problem?
QAQ